# Issue with splitting datetime R

Tags: r

I have a number of datetimes in the following format:

```
x <- "2018-10-19-18.00.00.000000"
```

I would like to split them into date and time.

as.Date works:

```
> as.Date(x)
[1] "2018-10-19"
```

But taking the time doesn't:

```
> format(as.POSIXct(x), format = "%H.%M.%OS6")
[1] "00.00.00.000000"
```

The output for time should be:

```
"18.00.00.000000"
```

Suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `format=` inside `as.POSIXct` as well as within `format(.)`, for a different purpose.

`as.POSIXct` assumes that the timestamp string will be in a particular unambiguous format, that's typically something like `"2018-10-19 18:00:00.000000"`, not the middle-dash and time-dots.

```r
x <- "2018-10-19-18.00.00.000000"
as.Date(x)
# [1] "2018-10-19"
as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%OS", tz="UTC")
# [1] "2018-10-19 18:00:00 UTC"
format(as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%OS", tz="UTC"), format = "%H.%M.%OS6")
# [1] "18.00.00.000000"
```

The reason it's giving all-`0`s for you is that your call to `as.POSIXct` is not parsing the time correctly, discarding it and giving you midnight:

```r
as.POSIXct(x, tz="UTC")
# [1] "2018-10-19 UTC"
```

(I used `tz="UTC"` here merely to prevent timezone problems, since I don't know the timezone of your original data. `tz=` is not required for this answer to be useful, though I do suggest that if you know what the timezone is and it is not encoded within the string, then you should be explicit about it to preserve reproducibility and such. I've been bitten way too many times due to timezone assumptions gone astray in automated environments.)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use `lubridate::ymd_hms`.

```
x <- "2018-10-19-18.00.00.000000"
x1 <- lubridate::ymd_hms(x)

as.Date(x1)
#[1] "2018-10-19"

format(x1, '%T')
#[1] "18:00:00"
```